How to calculate this expectation where the random matrxi lying on either side of a known matrix?
I don't know how to calculate the expectation
$
E\{\boldsymbol{XQX}^H\},
$
where $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{a\times a}$ is the random matrix that satisfies $E\{\boldsymbol{XX}^H\}=\boldsymbol{I}_a$, and $\boldsymbol{Q}\in\mathbb{C}^{a\times a}$ is known. How to simplify the form $E\{\boldsymbol{XQX}^H\}$?

If $X$ itself is sampled uniformly from the unitary group (so that not only $E(XX^H)=I$, but also $XX^H=I$ for every $X$ in the sample space), then $E(XQX^H)=\frac{\operatorname{tr}(Q)}{a}I_a$. In contrast, if you only know that $E(XX^H)=I$, I don’t see any way to simplify $E(XQX^H)$.
